# Hide/show element actions dependent on tab

Tags: plugin-development, elementaction

I have a custom element index with an element action to 'Approve' elements.

The element index has 'Live' and 'Staged' sources.

Where/how do I set it to only show this action on the 'staged' source OR just on a selection that contains an element that is not approved (latter probably better).

I've looked at the existing 'Delete' action and see that this uses a data attribute on the element index items 'data-deletable', how do I inject my own data attribute into the listing i.e. 'date-approvable'?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how I can do it, but it doesn't feel like the best way.

What I've done is hooked on to the `showActionTrigger` event, then hidden the button if the `source != 'staged'`

```
showActionTriggers: function() {
    this.base();
    if (this.$source.data('key') != 'staged')
    {
        $('#button-id').hide();  
    }
}
```

I have a feeling the best way is to build the JS on the element action class, under `getTriggerHtml`, but this will do for now.

Slowly getting my head around the CP js